# What are thickness minimums and best type of concrete to fill floor dips?

Tags: concrete, self-leveling-concrete

I have a large room (~775 sq. ft.) with concrete floor.  Prior owners had converted a garage to living space.  I need to level the floor before laying laminate.  For the final leveling, I'm planning on sectioning off more manageable areas and using self-leveling compound.

Before I do that, I'm finding much of the floor is at least 1/2" below level, with the worst spots going more than 2" low.  I have more measuring and calculating to do but if I only used SLC, I'd be looking at over $2000 in for around 70 bags of SLC.  Ugh.

My plan is to pre-fill much of the deeper areas up to within a quarter inch or so within level, then proceed with the self-leveling.

**Question 1** Is sand topping mix best for < 2" concrete fills?  Is there anything special to add to that?  For example, I've seen some references to adding more sand for certain thicknesses.  And related, I've been told it's not ideal, but for this application, all the blasting and priming one might normally do for a heavy traffic area is not necessary.  That's based on SLC following and laminate on top.

**Question 2** How thinly can I lay the concrete in this case?  I assumed I would at minimum prime before pouring the SLC.

**Bonus question**  Is this overall an okay approach for a DIYer who hasn't done much concrete beyond fence posts?

Comment: Are talking about low spots in the floor or  an over all  sloping angle that you want to bring up to level ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan Both.  There is one corner from which the rest generally slopes.  But from there, yes, there are a lot of areas that are more than a fairly regular slope.  I considered renting a grinder to take down some of that corner.  It would leave me with less of the same problem at some.